# Catching json error "wrong latitude and longitude" in Swift / SwiftUI

Tags: json, swift, error-handling

I am using openweathermap api. When wrong api key is entered or wrong latitude and longitude coordinates are entered, I get an error as follows. I show this error to the user with my own method, but I want to do it with a better method. I don't like my own code. I want to learn better. :)

**JSON Error:**

```
{"cod":"400","message":"wrong latitude"}
```

**T Model:**

```
struct Forecast: Codable {
    let daily: [Daily]
}

struct Daily: Codable {
    let dt: Date
    let temp: Temp
    let humidity: Int
    let weather: [Weather]
    let clouds: Int
    let pop: Double
}

struct Temp: Codable {
    let min: Double
    let max: Double
}

struct Weather: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let main: String
    let description: String
    let icon: String
}
```

**My Code:**

***Function 1:***

If the wrong latitude or longitude is entered in the first function, I catch the error because it cannot decode the incoming data.
Since the error sent by the json cannot be decoded, I wrote a different function (`getApiError(url: url) { }`) and within that function I am decoding the error from the json.

```
func getForecast<T: Decodable>(api url: String, dateDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy = .deferredToDate, keyDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy = .useDefaultKeys, completion: @escaping(Result<T, ApiError>) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
        completion(.failure(.error("Hatalı URL")))
        return
    }
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = dateDecodingStrategy
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = keyDecodingStrategy
    URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
        .map({ $0.data })
        .decode(type: T.self, decoder: decoder)
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink { taskCompletion in
            switch taskCompletion {
                
            case .finished:
                return
            case .failure(_):
       here ->   self.getApiError(url: url) { (result: Result<ApiErrorMessage, ApiError>) in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let item):
                        completion(.failure(.error("Api Key Hatası. \(item.cod)\n\(item.message)")))
                    case .failure(_):
                        completion(.failure(.error("Kod çözme hatası.")))
                    }
                }
            }
        } receiveValue: { decodeData in
            completion(.success(decodeData))
        }
        .store(in: &anyCancellable)
}
```

***Function 2:***

In this function I decode error from json. Do you think I did this right? I'm not sure of that.

```
func getApiError(url request: URL, dateDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy = .deferredToDate, keyDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy = .useDefaultKeys, completion: @escaping(Result<ApiErrorMessage, ApiError>) -> Void) {
    let request = URLRequest(url: request)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = dateDecodingStrategy
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = keyDecodingStrategy
    URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
        .map({ $0.data })
        .decode(type: ApiErrorMessage.self, decoder: decoder)
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink { taskCompletion in
            switch taskCompletion {
            case .finished:
                return
            case .failure(let decodingError):
                completion(.failure(.error("Kod çözme hatası. \(decodingError.localizedDescription)")))
            }
        } receiveValue: { decodeData in
            completion(.success(decodeData))
        }
        .store(in: &anyCancellable)
}
```

Comment: Where does the guy named 'T.self' come from?

Comment: Nobody knows what kind of data the T guy deals with.

Comment: which openweathermap api are you trying to access? 
I just cannot see where there is a `Forecast` json as part of the response.

Answer (score 0):

A smooth way in Swift is an enum with associated values. You get a `success` case containing the weather data and a `failure` case with the error message.

The enum first decodes `cod` as an `Int`. If this succeeds the weather data is decoded, If not `cod` is `String` and the error data is decoded.

Replace `WeatherData` with the root object name and decode `Response.self`. It can be used similar to the `Result` type

```
enum Response : Decodable {
    case success(WeatherData), failure(ErrorData)
    
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case cod }
    
    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {
        let containar = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let singleContainer = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            let _ = try containar.decode(Int.self, forKey: .cod)
            self = .success(try singleContainer.decode(WeatherData.self))
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            self = .failure(try singleContainer.decode(ErrorData.self))
        }
    }
}

struct ErrorData : Decodable {
    let cod, message: String
}
```

On the caller side `switch` on the result of the `JSONDecoder`

```
switch result {
    case .success(let weatherData): print(weatherData)
    case .success(let error): print(error.message)
}
```